# slightly confused

Tags: electrical-panel

Separate grounding of a sub panel in a separate building should be thought about in two untalked about instances as of yet. In the case of an isolated circuit i.e. a computer or electronic designated circuit, any current surge caused by an internal system or external source could affect electronics. 
A separate isolated ground at a recommended distance is used so as to help minimize a backfeed current in either direction. In the event of a lightning strike on unattached structures, a surge to  other structures can be minimized as in the case of an internal component located in one of the structures.

So, if a sub panel in a separate structure has its own ground, with the neutral bonded to the ground only at the sub panel it is servicing, yet also continuing to the grid through ordinary path.....am I out in orit??

Comment: Welcome, Greg. Your question isn't entirely clear. I suggest reading your first and last sentences aloud and revising. Then, edit your title to ask an actual question. Please [take the tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com) if you're not familiar with SE network protocol.

Comment: As far as the sub panel is concerned it depends on the date of install on what is required. Curent code requires 4 wire (2 hot, 1 neutral & ground) as this is a sub the neutral is isolated from the ground an since it is a separate building additional ground rods are required or other grounding methods like plate, pipe or ufer.

Comment: The "edit" button is found below your message, below the line "`electrical-panel` Edit tags" and actually in the line of words "share **edit** delete".

Answer (score 2):

You've stated 3 sentences as fact (I don't agree with them), and you described a scenario that's pretty ugly, and then asked "am I off-base?" I assume you mean.  Yes.  Power distribution Earthing is *serious business*, and it doesn't lend itself to wild-guessing by experts of distant fields.

Notably, electronics types tend to have huge confusion about how Equipment Safety Earthing relates to common current return (moreso *how it does not*), and they tend to only look at reasons which relate to *their* concerns rather than all the concerns which define safety standards in earthing.

---

First, hot(s) and neutral are active conductors.  Intentionally bringing lightning onto an active conductor is *the silliest thing you could possibly do in the whole wide world*.  Lightning is going to invade your safety earthing/grounding system. Why give it a shortcut to neutral?  Yet another of 100 reasons you should not bond neutral to ground anywhere except where Code calls for.... *and that's only one place*.

### Isolated systems

Do not work like you think they do.  If you put a bunch of stuff on 1 circuit, it is not an isolated system at all. If you take hot/neutral out of a panel and sever ground and drive a separate grounding rod, that's *still* not an isolated system, it's a wiring mistake.

If you want an isolated system, obtain an **isolation transformer**. Feed the primary with normal power.  The secondary now provides a *separately derived system* (and it can be a small system), isolated at whichever insulation strength the transformer happens to have.

You can leave it fully isolated, throw a GFCI device on it to catch anything that could shock, call it a day.

Or you can add your own grounding rod and earth it -- this helps discharge ESD but also gives lightning a speedway to your equipment.  On a single-circuit isolated system with GFCI I would not bond neutral and ground on the secondary side of the transformer - why help lightning get to neutral?  Make it leap 2 frontiers: between machine chassis and machine supply conductors (H/H/N); and across the transformer's insulation from H/H/N[isolated] to N[connected]. That with some good lightning arresting may suffice.

### Your subpanel wiring has issues

Your supply coming from the main panel is one of these two:

- Hot, [Hot], Neutral and Ground coming as separate wires.  This is modern.
- Hot, [Hot], and Neutral coming as separate wires.  No ground wire from the main.  This is obsolete and hazardous.  Obviously if you have valuable equipment, "obsolete and hazardous" is worth fixing.

If you do not have a ground wire and want one, you can take advantage of Code changes which allow a ground wire to be retrofit separately from subpanel back to main.  You can lay it any way feasible (that is legal) and it does not need to follow the same route (normally, since current never flows on ground wires, equal currents is not a factor).

If you do not have a ground wire and do not want one, the aforementioned *separately derived system* method as described above can achieve the isolation without having to wire a separate ground.  The isolation transformer cures a multitude of ills!

If you *do* have a separate neutral and ground wire running back to the main panel, then **neutral and ground must be separated in the subpanel - period**.  That is simply Code, and that is how it is.  Further, since it is an outbuilding, you also need local ground rod(s) to tie the ground (NOT NEUTRAL) to nearby earth.  Yes, you need both the ground rod and the ground wire.  Really.  The ground wire solves problems that are not on your radar.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're asking about lightning safety in a situation where the main building provides power to a second building, and both buildings have their own grounding system.  That's actually less safe than having only a single ground at the main building's service panel.

There are two main scenarios to worry about when you use multiple grounds.

First, if lightning were to strike anywhere near the buildings, it would create a large voltage gradient in the soil.  This means the voltage in the soil at the location of the strike is very high, but the soil's resistance causes the voltage to get much lower as you get farther away.  If you have two ground rods, they're almost certainly going to have very different voltages resulting from the lightning.  So, current will try to flow from one rod to the other.  Because the lowest resistance path will be through your wiring, much of that current will go through your wires and buildings, potentially damaging equipment and/or starting a fire.

Second, if lightning were to strike the power lines feeding the main building, you would be providing two paths to ground for the surge.  Because of the earth's resistance, the current would be divided and both paths would be used. 
 The current that goes to ground at the main building's service entrance isn't nearly as dangerous as the current that goes through the main building's wiring to reach the second building.  Again, there's an increased risk of fire and equipment damage.

If you're willing to invest enough time and money, it's possible to protect both buildings from lightning using multiple bonded grounds, but that's beyond the scope of this answer.  If you're interested in further reading, see [this question about lightning and radio antennas](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/51/how-can-i-protect-equipment-against-a-lightning-strike).  Even though it's not about subpanels and second buildings, the lightning safety aspects still apply.